What does 3EA, 3FA or 3IW mean on a potentiometer?
I'm trying to figure out markings on potentiometers in a guitar amp.  Below the usual "B100K", etc. there are additional inscriptions like "3EA", "3FA" or "3IW".  What could they possibly mean?  I'm attaching pictures.  The amp is made by Carlsbro, it says "Manufactured in England", I think the parts are original.  A manufacturer's logo is clearly visible, do you recognize it?  (If I knew their name I could try to look the info up in their catalog.)
Some of the pots' markings end with "A", like B100KA shown below;  others don't.  What does it stand for?


My search found that it is not "dp" but JP for Jung Poong just as someone else thought. JP is a current group that makes many different products from hardware to PCB but this was from a former factory in S. Korea, no longer in production since the internet came out, IMHO.  It is not "Young Poon" ;) nor is it found on any webpage on the Internet Archive.
By convention, traceability info goes below the part number with date and factory info converted to code letters for their use only.  The 3 could have meant 1983 for all we know.
What you need to know is the taper type and torque for matching the feel and the material (cermet, Carbon, or wirewound).  Get two of each if you need replacements, if they need to match.  Tone controls will be linear while volume controls will be taper.
Generally different companies will use some audio taper such as 20% or 30% taper which is not logarithmic but close enough for old audio controls.  If you can measure a good one for the %-rotation vs %-resistance, a linear pot will be 50% in mid-position.
You can look up Alpha, Bourns, Piher and CTS for their offerings or ask guitar shops for replacement parts, like https://nextgenguitars.ca/categories/potentiometers.html.
So the A suffix will be a different taper than the std p/n with no suffix.
more pots  https://picclick.com/Business-Industrial/Electrical-Equipment-Supplies/Electronic-Components-Semiconductors/Passive-Components/Potentiometers-Variable-Resistors/Potentiometers/

This is ink instead of stamped into the metal,  possibly counterfeit?

It just looks too old for that. They  stamp then smear with ink to fill.

yeah, agreed, I wasn't looking carefully enough.

These are stamped with no ink, I just chose the lighting angle for maximum readability.  Sorry I've caused confusion with my photography technique. :)

No problem. It could also be painted and burnished or fine sanding.

It's probably a lot code. If there was a faulty batch they could advise the customer not to use any pots with lot code "31W", for example. It may be a code for the year / day / plant / machine, etc., but there are only three characters so there can't be that much information in there.

There's a logo image I knocked up with Inkscape for Google's image search but it returns a bunch of "JP" logos.
